# How to split this string and identify first sentence after last '*'?

Tags: c#, string

I'm getting a string similar to the following back from the database:

```
The object of the following is to do:
* blah 1 * blah 2 * blah 3 * blah 4. Some more extremely uninteresting
text. Followed by yet another sentence
full of extremely uninteresting text.
Thankfully this is the last sentence.
```

I need to format this so that each `*` represents a bullet point, and the sentence after the last `*` goes onto a new line, ideally as follows:

```
The object of the following is to do: 

* blah 1
* blah 2 
* blah 3 
* blah 4. 

Some more extremely uninteresting
text. Followed by yet another sentence
full of extremely uninteresting text.
Thankfully this is the last sentence.
```

It's easy enough to split the string by the `*` character and replace that with `<br /> *`. I'm using the following for that:

```
string description = GetDescription();

description = description.Replace("*", "<br />*"); // it's going onto a web page.
```

but the result this gives me is:

```
The object of the following is to do: 

* blah 1 
* blah 2 
* blah 3 
* blah 4. Some more extremely uninteresting text. Followed by yet
another sentence full of extremely
uninteresting text. Thankfully this is
the last sentence.
```

I'm having a bit of difficulty identifying the fist sentence after the last '*' so I can put a break there too. Can somebody show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it can be assumed that the `fist sentence after the last '*'` is separated by a period - then you can do the following:

1. Replace the input by finding all `*` characters
2. Find the last `<br>` and then find the first `.` after it.
3. Recombine the fragments, replacing `*` with `<br/>*`

Here's some code to get you going: (it may not be perfect). I'm using `string.Split()` here rather than `string.Replace()` because I find it makes the logic easier to follow. The trick is that the last subRegion consists of two parts (the bullet and the sentence after the bullet).

```
string inputText = "...";
string[] subRegions = inputText.Split( "*" );
// split final region into bullet and sentance based on first period...
string[] lastRegions = subRegions[subRegion.Length-1].Split(new[]{'.'},2);
// replace the final subregion with the combined parts (bullet/sentence)
subRegions[subRegions.Length-1] = string.Join(". <br/>",lastRegions);
// combine all subregions together, replacing `*` with bulletized breaks.
string finalText = string.Join( "<br/>*", subRegions );
```

Answer (score 4):

You need some way to determine the *other* delimiter in your last sentence. You could do a global replace for `*` to `<br /> *` as you do currently, then find the last instance of `*` and replace the next `.` or whatever delimiter with `. <br />`.

### Update

Fixed the order of `<br /> .` to `. <br />` as @Shaded pointed out.

Comment: You'd probably actually want to replace it with '. <br />' so that the period doesn't jump with the last sentence.

Still +1 cause that's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add another * after the blah 4

Comment: If I added another * after the blah 4, it would be replaced by "<br /> *", so there would be a * leading the sentences following the bullets

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that the last bullet ends with a '.', then something like this might work:

```
string description =
    "The object of the following is to do: * blah 1 * blah 2 * blah 3 * blah 4. Some more extremely uninteresting text. Followed by yet another sentence full of extrememly uninteresting text. Thankfully this is the last sentence.";            
int idx = description.IndexOf('.', description.LastIndexOf('*'));
description = description.Insert(idx+1, "<br />");
description = description.Replace("*", "<br />*");
```

Basically it finds the first occurrence of '.' after the last '*. If you have more separator characters you could use those as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not being a C# expert but I'd be thinking to "split" the string on "*" into an array to get all your bullets and then either split the last item in the array (your last bullet with the sentence) or use a regex to grab the sentence.

i.e. Pseudo code

```
List bullets = description.split('*');
String lastSentence = bullets(bullets.size() + 1).replace('^\*.*?\.', '');
```

Where the regex is meant to strip *anything up to the first fullstop.

Of course this approach might not work if your laast sentence has a '*' in it of course :)